# Let $f$ a continuous function. Is $f(cl(D))=cl(f(D))$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^n$ a continuous function and $D\subset \mathbb R^n$ a compact set. Do we have

1)$$f\big(\text{closure}(D)\big)=\text{closure}\big(f(D)\big)$$

2) $$f\big(\text{int}(D)\big)=\text{int}\big(f(D)\big)$$

3) $$f\big(\text{Boundary}(D)\big)=\text{Boundary}\big(f(D)\big)$$

I don't want proofs, I just want to know if the previous equalities are true or false.

Comment: Why did someone downvoted ? It's a good question ! I don't think that $2)$ is true since Möbius transformation can transform the inside to the outside. But those transformation are in $\mathbb C$, and may be your question is only for $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question can be extend to $\mathbb C^n$.

Comment: @Surb By the way $\Bbb C^n\cong\Bbb R^{2n}$ so it's the same question either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The definition of a continuous function implies only one of the subsets in the above, that is:

$$f\mbox{ is continuous}\iff \forall A\subseteq X, f(\overline{A})\subseteq\overline{f(A)}$$
$$f\mbox{ is continuous}\iff \forall A\subseteq X, f^{-1}(A^\circ)\subseteq [f^{-1}(A)]^\circ$$

(Note that $\overline{A}$ is a notation for the closure of $A$, and $A^\circ$ is the interior, in case you haven't seen those before.) Thus one can guess that in general none of the equalities is true. However, because we are assuming that $A$ is compact, it isn't quite this simple.

In your case, $D$ is known to be compact and hence closed, so the first one simplifies to $f(D)=\overline{f(D)}$, i.e. $f(D)$ is closed. This is true because the image of a compact set is compact and hence closed.

For the second case, we want $f(D^\circ)=[f(D)]^\circ$. This implies that $f(D^\circ)$ is open, so $f$ acts like an open map. Again this is not generally true, not even if we restrict to the interior of compact regions: Consider $f(x)=x^2$ as a function $\Bbb R^1\to\Bbb R^1$, and take $D=[-1,1]$. Then $D^\circ=(-1,1)$ and $f(D^\circ)=[0,1)$ which is not open.

The third case is basically just the set difference of the first two so it won't be true either; with the same example we have $\partial D=\{-1,1\}$ and $f(\partial D)=\{1\}$, while $f(D)=[0,1]$ and $\partial f(D)=\{0,1\}$.

There is an interesting theorem in complex analysis called the [open mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29) which suggests that question $2$ is true in one direction under certain circumstances. If $f:\Bbb C\to\Bbb C$ is non-constant holomorphic, then it is an open map, so $f(D^\circ)=f(D^\circ)^\circ\subseteq f(D)^\circ$. However we still don't have the reverse implication: consider again $f(z)=z^2$, and $D=\{z\mid \Re[z]\ge0\land |z|\le 1\}$ (the right unit semicircle). Then $D^\circ=\{z\mid \Re[z]>0\land |z|>1\}$, $f(D^\circ)=\{z\mid z\notin\Bbb R^{\le0}\land |z|>1\}$, while $f(D)=\{z\mid |z|\le 1\}$ and $f(D)^\circ=\{z\mid |z|>1\}$.

Comment: Why the downvote? If it's because you didn't want proofs, then you should ask on chat or something - the supplementary information here wouldn't fit under that restriction, and it would do a disservice to future visitors.

Comment: I didn't downvote, your answer is perfect :-) Just a question, since $ f(\partial D)\neq \partial f(D)$ why when we want to compute $f(D)$, we always ask to compute $f(\partial D)$ ? For exemple, I have to compute $f(D_i)$ for $D_1=\{x+iy\mid x,y\geq 0, x+y\leq 1\}$, $D_2=\{x+iy\mid |x|\leq 2, |y|\leq 1\}$ and $f(z)=z^2$ ($f:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C$). And the hint is "compute first $f(\partial D_i)$". Then, why if $f(\partial D_i)\neq \partial f(D_i)$ they ask to compute $f(\partial D_i)$ ?

Answer (score 3):

1.True

2.False

3.False

Counter-example for 2,3: $f(x)=x^2$ on $[-1,1]$.